# SML: Determining Type of Function

Tags: functional-programming, sml

Suppose all I know about a function is that it is of type:

```
int list -> int * string -> int
```

Is there any way of knowing in advance whether this means:

`(int list -> int * string) -> int` or `int list -> (int * string -> int)`?

Thanks,

bclayman

Answer (score 3):

`->` is right associative in SML type annotations, so `int list -> (int * string -> int)` is correct.

Consider this simple experiment in the REPL:

```
- fun add x y = x+y;
val add = fn : int -> int -> int
```

`add` is a function which, when fed an int, returns a function, namely the function which sends `y` to `x + y` -- hence its type is `int -> (int ->int)`. It isn't a function which, when a fed a function from ints to ints outputs an int (which is what `(int -> int) -> int` would be). A somewhat artificial example of the later sort of thing is:

```
- fun apply_to_zero_and_increment f = 1 + f(0);
val apply_to_zero_and_increment = fn : (int -> int) -> int
```

If I define `fun g(x) = x + 5` then `apply_to_zero_and_increment g` returns 6.